# Constructing simple zip code polygon map in CartoDB?

Tags: polygon, carto, cartography

I'm new to using **CartoDB**.

I want to produce a map that depicts multiple layers, the first of which is simple **zip code** polygons (i.e. polygons outlining an area defined by a postal zip code).

I would ideally like to stick to using CartoDB to do this.

I then plan to add other layers but need to start with zip codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can [geocode](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/how_to_georeference.html) a list of zipcodes that you can upload as a regular dataset, but probably it's better for you to find them directly from their source and upload that dataset.

If you're looking for USA zipcodes, I recommend you to take a look at the ZCTA datasets that Census US offers. This dataset is the lighter one I found for these regions: http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2013/cb_2013_us_zcta510_500k.zip